# User tagging inside a text paragraph program logic

Tags: android, ios, angularjs, node.js, logic

Hi I have a requirement for a basic social networking application.

My question may seems to be stupid, this is just to get the perspectives and programmatic logic from you guys.

My requirement is that the users must be able to mention other users name inside a test post exactly same as facebook. See the image below
[image]

I would like to display the post as same as in facebook

[image]

Can somebody suggest me some cool idea to do it.

My plan was the following.

Create a post text similar to this "@user-userid this is a test" and include the user details in post details.Replace the "@user-userid" with the name from the post detail.

Is there any better idea to do the same??

Thanks in advance....

PS: I need to do the same logic on Android, IOS and angularJs web application.

Answer (score 0):

A possible workflow could be listen on edit made on your edittext if the current word starts with '@' (or your key letter) check in your datas if you have a match with this word and then add a recycler view with matching datas and autocoplete when an item is selected.

Regards,

Comment: Thanks @user1796260 What would be the result data text of the post which I should save on the database???

Comment: a nice way is to save a json with the text and an array with each reference and each reference is defined by his text his starting point in the whole string his length and the link to the detailed data (profile etc)